# Create variable based on other values in other dataset

Tags: r

I want to create variables counting the number of seats of each party for each municipality so I get the following:

[image: Municipality]

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          municipality= c("Aa en Hunze","Aa en Hunze",
                       "Aa en Hunze","Aalburg","Aalburg","Aalsmeer",
                       "Aalsmeer","Aalten","Aalten","Achtkarspelen","Achtkarspelen",
                       "Alblasserdam","Alblasserdam","Alblasserdam",
                       "Albrandswaard","Albrandswaard","Almelo","Almelo","Almelo",
                       "Almelo","Almere","Almere","Almere","Almere",
                       "Alphen-Chaam","Alphen-Chaam","Ameland","Ameland","Amersfoort",
                       "Amersfoort","Amersfoort","Amersfoort","Amstelveen",
                       "Amstelveen","Amstelveen","Amstelveen","Amsterdam",
                       "Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Amsterdam"),
            party = c("VVD","CDA",
                       "Democraten 66 (D66)","CDA","VVD","CDA","VVD","CDA","VVD","CDA",
                       "VVD","CDA","Democraten 66 (D66)","VVD","VVD","CDA",
                       "CDA","Democraten 66 (D66)","SP (Socialistische Partij)",
                       "VVD","Democraten 66 (D66)","VVD",
                       "SP (Socialistische Partij)","CDA","CDA","VVD","CDA","VVD",
                       "Democraten 66 (D66)","VVD","CDA","SP (Socialistische Partij)",
                       "VVD","Democraten 66 (D66)","CDA",
                       "SP (Socialistische Partij)","Democraten 66 (D66)",
                       "SP (Socialistische Partij)","VVD","CDA"),
      seats= c(3L,2L,2L,3L,1L,6L,6L,7L,
                       2L,5L,1L,3L,2L,2L,6L,2L,6L,4L,4L,3L,6L,5L,
                       4L,2L,4L,1L,3L,1L,9L,5L,4L,4L,9L,8L,3L,3L,
                       14L,6L,6L,1L)
)
```

I want to create for example a variable called VVD and then all number of seats per municipality.

<sup>Created on 2020-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I don't know how to code this in r, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use`xtabs` to count the *seats* per *municipality* and *party*.

```
xtabs(seats ~ municipality + party, df)
#               party
#municipality    CDA Democraten 66 (D66) SP (Socialistische Partij) VVD
#  Aa en Hunze     2                   2                          0   3
#  Aalburg         3                   0                          0   1
#  Aalsmeer        6                   0                          0   6
#  Aalten          7                   0                          0   2
#  Achtkarspelen   5                   0                          0   1
#  Alblasserdam    3                   2                          0   2
#  Albrandswaard   2                   0                          0   6
#  Almelo          6                   4                          4   3
#  Almere          2                   6                          4   5
#  Alphen-Chaam    4                   0                          0   1
#  Ameland         3                   0                          0   1
#  Amersfoort      4                   9                          4   5
#  Amstelveen      3                   8                          3   9
#  Amsterdam       1                  14                          6   6
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to put this in a dataframe?

Comment: I used  the following code: as.data.frame.matrix(tab) 
I think it works. Thank you so much!